# How to select rows that do not start with some str in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to select rows that the values do not start with some str. For example, I have a pandas `df`, and I want to select data do not start with `t`, and `c`. In this sample, the output should be `mext1` and `okl1`.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'col':['text1','mext1','cext1','okl1']})
df

    col
0   text1
1   mext1
2   cext1
3   okl1
```

I want this:

```
    col
0   mext1
1   okl1
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use the str accessor to get string functionality. The `get` method can grab a given index of the string.

```
df[~df.col.str.get(0).isin(['t', 'c'])]

     col
1  mext1
3   okl1
```

Looks like you can use `startswith` as well with a tuple (and not a list) of the values you want to exclude.

```
df[~df.col.str.startswith(('t', 'c'))]
```

Comment: This solution scales better +1

Comment: TKS, How if I add a new column to fill values? @Ted Petrou

Comment: Thanks - seems crucial to understand the ~ symbol (bitwise NOT).

Answer (score 24):

***option 1***
use `str.match` and negative look ahead

```
df[df.col.str.match('^(?![tc])')]
```

***option 2***
within `query`

```
df.query('col.str[0] not list("tc")')
```

***option 3***
`numpy` broadcasting

```
df[(df.col.str[0][:, None] == ['t', 'c']).any(1)]
```

---

```
         col
1  mext1
3   okl1
```

---

***time testing***

```
def ted(df):
    return df[~df.col.str.get(0).isin(['t', 'c'])]

def adele(df):
    return df[~df['col'].str.startswith(('t','c'))]

def yohanes(df):
    return df[df.col.str.contains('^[^tc]')]

def pir1(df):
    return df[df.col.str.match('^(?![tc])')]

def pir2(df):
    return df.query('col.str[0] not in list("tc")')

def pir3(df):
    df[(df.col.str[0][:, None] == ['t', 'c']).any(1)]

functions = pd.Index(['ted', 'adele', 'yohanes', 'pir1', 'pir2', 'pir3'], name='Method')
lengths = pd.Index([10, 100, 1000, 5000, 10000], name='Length')
results = pd.DataFrame(index=lengths, columns=functions)

from string import ascii_lowercase

for i in lengths:
    a = np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), i)
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col=a))
    for j in functions:
        results.set_value(
            i, j,
            timeit(
                '{}(df)'.format(j),
                'from __main__ import df, {}'.format(j),
                number=1000
            )
        )

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(8, 12))
results.plot(ax=axes[0], title='All Methods')
results.drop('pir2', 1).plot(ax=axes[1], title='Drop `pir2`')
results[['ted', 'adele', 'pir3']].plot(ax=axes[2], title='Just the fast ones')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice to see the plot output @piRSquared Always interesting to read your posts Sir, +1

Answer (score 16):

You can use `str.startswith` and negate it.

```
    df[~df['col'].str.startswith('t') & 
       ~df['col'].str.startswith('c')]

col
1   mext1
3   okl1
```

Or the better option, with multiple characters in a tuple as per  @Ted Petrou:

```
df[~df['col'].str.startswith(('t','c'))]

    col
1   mext1
3   okl1
```

Comment: Looks like you can use `startswith` with a tuple and not a list to contain multiple values. No idea why a tuple works but not a list.

Comment: Nice, I tried the list and not a tuple so thanks for that  @TedPetrou

Answer (score 5):

Just another alternative in case you prefer regex:

```
df1[df1.col.str.contains('^[^tc]')]
```

Comment: You shouldn't need lambda here

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `apply` method.

Take your question as a example, the code is like this

```
df[df['col'].apply(lambda x: x[0] not in ['t', 'c'])]
```

I think `apply` is a more general and flexible method.